# CSGO - Banned competitive or a penalty of a few months / years?

Tags: steam, counter-strike-global-offensive

I think I'm banned in competitive csgo, I was wondering when I'm banned, they block the competitive line? or you can throw at it, only without earn points, how it works? why this happened to me only, I was "Banned" at the time did not read the VAC message, I am now playing legitimate competitive because I can still join the queue, without fraud, but I do not earn points to climb, silver for 2 always. If anyone knows of a solution or what really happened. Sorry English, Google Translate, I hope you can understand the text.

Comment: Was it a VAC ban? If so I *think* that means you're essentially banned from all official servers, and any third party server that is VAC secured, which is most of them.

Comment: You mention you can still play competitive with no problems but you aren't seeing a rank increase.  Just because you win some games doesn't necessarily mean you will rank up immediately and see results.  It takes a lot of wins and points to earn a rank up.

Answer (score 5):

There are a few reason why you might be unable to connect to a competitive round:

## Competitive Ban

You can receive this ban for doing any of the following:

- Too much damage to teammates. (3 warnings)
- Harming a teammate at the start of the round (Instant ban)
- Leaving a match after you have pressed the **ACCEPT** button.
- Abusing the kick system.

Keep in mind that a matchmaking ban will be issued regardless of whether or not an infraction was intentional.

## VAC Ban

VAC is Valve's anticheat system, it is very accurate and there are almost no false positives. 
*FACT: There has only been one false ban, and this was due to a game having a broken DLL.*
You will be VAC Banned for the following reasons:

- Cheating! D:

You will not be VAC banned for any other reason, face it you cheated and got caught. You will no longer be able to connect to any other VAC Secured server!

[Source: Valve Knowledgebase](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=1203-WJCV-7019)

Comment: That link should say "Valve Knowledgebase"

Answer (score 1):

TLDR at bottom

There are many reasons to not being able to connect to CSGO competitive matches.

### COOLDOWNS

you will receive a Competitive cooldown of varied length depending of the amount of infractions which you have committed. An Competitive cooldown is issued when you:

- Dealing over 300 team damage
- Killing 3 Teammates
- Abandoning the match
- Failing to reconnect within 3 minutes of disconnecting
- Being Kicked for a certain amount of times
- Kicking too many players

### BANS

If a user has reported you, and after reviewing the footage of that specific match, you are found to be guilty, you will be issued 1 of the two bans, or in some cases, both.

1. Minor Disturbance Bans 
   You will attain one of these bans if you are reported for Griefing, Abusive Voice Chat, Or Abusive Text Chat, and are found guilty of doing so. Your account will be banned for a large amount of time (Unsure about exact duration).
2. Major Infraction Bans
   These bans are attained if you are reported for Aim Assistance, Visual Assistance, and Other Assistance, or the VAC system catches you cheating. These will result in a permanent ban from competitive matches, and a VAC ban will even prevent you from entering any official Valve server.

### ACCOUNT GLITCH

For some users, your PC/game cache might be glitched, causing you to not be able to connect to matches, despite not having committed any infractions. A very common case of this is the "Appear Button" not appearing. There many solutions to this, and I am not going to list them here, but the solution that solved this problem for my PC was simply to reinstall the game.

Hopefully this clarifies any of your questions. I can attempt to further help you if you provide further details into your problem.

After re-reading your text, it seems like you have previously received a ban, (Possibly VAC ban) and after the ban has expired, you can no longer rank up. I doubt that this has occurred before, but maybe, if you try some more, you can rank up. Maybe it's not anything having to do with your ban, maybe you're just stuck. I can't help you to rank up, sorry.

If you provide more details of your problem in better English, I might be able to help you better.

### TLDR

- explained cooldowns and bans
- seems like he cannot rank up from silver 2
- cannot really help him if it's not glitch
- if better message is provided I will try to help